# Clarifying an answered question

Tags: discussion

I asked a [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/165627/when-does-paulis-exclusion-principle-kick-in/165651#165651) some time ago and, after reading the answers and thinking the problem on my own, I realized that my question wasn't clear enough.

I now have a better way to ask the question and also know the answer (knowing the right question leads to the right answer). Should I edit my question and add an answer myself? I worry that this would leave the answers which are already there a bit out of context.

What is a good way to proceed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Should I edit my question and add an answer myself?

The answer to this can found with this question: *If you update your post with your new/actual question, do the existing answers still answer your query?*

If they do answer the new question, feel free to edit it in. If they do not answer the new question, make a new post (and reference the original and emphasize how it is different, as some might want to close as a duplicate).

> Should I edit my question and add an answer myself?

For the first half, as above; for the second half, absolutely. [Self-answered questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) are (almost<sup>1</sup>) always welcome.

<sup>1 Caveats include off-topic questions, such as homework or non-mainstream physics.</sup>